# Дробные числительные в предложениях - дополнение или обстоятельство?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, числительные

> Я потерял две третьих своего товара.
> Человек использует лишь одну десятую мозга.

Чем в этих предложениях являются числительные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как известно, в сочетании с существительными числительное обычно образует **нечленимое синтаксическое целое** и выступает вместе с ним в функции **одного члена** предложения.

*Я потерял (что?) две третьих своего товара.*
*Человек использует (что?) лишь одну десятую мозга.*

Таким образом, дополнениями являются **неразложимые сочетания**: две третьих товара, одну десятую мозга.  Частица «лишь» примыкает к дополнению, отдельным членом предложения не является. Местоимение  – это  определение для существительного «товара».

Далее можно привести **примеры,** где подобные сочетания играют другую синтаксическую роль.

Дробные числительные в предложении могут выступать в роли:

• подлежащего: Три четвертых веса пшеницы есть крахмал (газ.);

• обстоятельства: Только одну десятую часть своего времени человек занимается активным умственным трудом (газ.);

• дополнения: Мы потеряли две пятых нашего свободного времени (газ.).

Примеры взяты из Интернета https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5cdc300bc3886300b3495644/leksikogrammaticheskie-razriady-chislitelnyh-ih-morfologicheskie-svoistva-5eaa5df7d1669d6032e8e8db

Comment: Спасибо! Если можно, еще спрошу. Три четвертых веса пшеницы - такое подлежащее, или все же без пшеницы?

Comment: Я полагаю,  что всё-таки без "пшеницы", это обычный распространитель. В счетный оборот входит числительное  и существительное, именно они составляют неразложимое сочетание.

Answer (score 2):

В данных предложениях числительные являются частью сложного дополнения:

*Я потерял* (что?) ***две третьих** своего **товара**.*

Потеряны были *две третьих товара*. Невозможно отделить слово *товара* без потери смысла.

*Человек использует* (что?) ***лишь одну десятую мозга**.*

Используют *лишь одну десятую мозга*. Усилительная частица *лишь* не является отдельным членом предложения — к ней нельзя задать вопрос. Она исполняет исключительно служебную роль, усиливая сочетание *одну десятую мозга*.

В обоих примерах сочетания являются прямым объектом глагола — второстепенным членом предложения — и отвечают на вопрос косвенного (винительного) падежа. По определению, оба сочетания являются дополнениями.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и бы и предположила. Но на сайте https://kakpishem.ru/chasti-rechi/chislitelnoe/kakimi-chlenami-predlozheniya-sluzhat-chislitelnye.html эти предложения разобраны по-разному. В предложении про мозг числительное является обстоятельством. Вот тут я и задумалась. Я не вижу между между этими предложениями разницу.

Comment: Не существует термина "составное дополнение".

Comment: Непопулярное название, причем оно связано с конкретной темой (составных сказуемых) и характеризуется наличием связок. Здесь же вопрос о дробных числительных. Вы не относите счетный оборот к неразложимым сочетаниям? Мы купили семь роз. Это тоже составое (или сложное) дополнение?

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий на тему о «составных дополнениях»**

Я бы рекомендовала вам обновить литературу, которой вы пользуетесь. Посмотрите учебник для вузов Кустовой, она использует термин «нечленимые словосочетания»  (стр. 64, п. 4) [https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

Описательная грамматика – это одно из самых динамичных направлений, там всё очень быстро меняется. Что касается числового оборота, то уже в младшей школе его разбирают **как единый член предложения**, но только уж не как составное дополнение или подлежащее. Этот термин **совершенно не походит к числовому обороту**.  К примеру,  сложным словосочетанием можно назвать сочетание «пять школьных тетрадей», но только не «пять тетрадей».

Числовой оборот имеет **особую структуру**, если вы в этом разбираетесь. К примеру,  прямое дополнение должно иметь В.п., и поэтому числительное используется в форме В.п., но при этом оно задает Р.п. существительному. Получается **словосочетание с подчинительной связью управления**.

А в косвенных падежах их **роли меняются, управление переходит в согласование**, главным словом становится существительное. И вот такую структуру вы хотите обозначить как составное дополнение,  как будто оно составлено из нескольких дополнений.

Вы хотя бы **какую-то логику в этом видите?** Так мы весь синтаксис можем назвать составным.

Comment: Спасибо за книгу!

Comment: Пожалуйста, Nadezhda! Вам она уж точно будет полезна. Успехов вам в освоении русского языка.